# .cpp to .o files in Makefile

Tags: makefile

How can I generate .o file corresponding to all the .cpp files in a directory using Makefile?
I have a directory that contains .cpp files. Now, I want to compile them in .o files. The name of the .o files should be same as corresponding .cpp files. What should I do?

Actually, I already had an implementation but I am not sure how it work

```
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
            // Recipe //
```

Comment: You should write rules to compile the .cpp files into .o ones. Show us what you tried ...

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: GNU Make already knows how to compile `cpp` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SRCS=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.o )

%.o: %.cpp 
   $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

Let me add some more explaination to it.

`SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)` - It will list all the .cpp files under `SRCDIR` directory and will assign to `SRCS`

`OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)` - It will replace all the files with .cpp listed from the above statement to `.o` ex: `main.cpp` would be changed to `main.o` and assigned to OBJS

`$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp` - Object files depends on respective `.cpp` files and in the rule you can write rule to create object files

The `%` character can be used for wildcard pattern-matching, to provide generic targets. For example:

```
%.o: %.c
[TAB] actions
```

When `%` appears in the dependency list, it is replaced with the same string that was used to perform substitution in the target.

If the above explanation is not clear just go through the Makefile Basics once and try writing without using special variables and then go to the complex rules.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the use of "%" here. Also I think its a typo, so modify .c to .cpp in the explanation